# resource not found with Azure OpenAI service

Tags: azure, azure-openai

when I am using this demo code to use the Azure OpenAI service in Java 11:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure;

import com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient;
import com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClientBuilder;
import com.azure.ai.openai.models.*;
import com.azure.core.credential.AzureKeyCredential;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class AzureOpenAIClient {

    public static void getChatCompletion(){
        String azureOpenaiKey = "the-key";
        String endpoint = "https://reddwarfcv.openai.azure.com/";
        String deploymentOrModelId = "gpt-35-turbo";

        OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenaiKey))
                .buildClient();

        List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.SYSTEM).setContent("You are a helpful assistant."));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent("Does Azure OpenAI support customer managed keys?"));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.ASSISTANT).setContent("Yes, customer managed keys are supported by Azure OpenAI?"));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent("Do other Azure Cognitive Services support this too?"));

        ChatCompletions chatCompletions = client.getChatCompletions(deploymentOrModelId, new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages));

        System.out.printf("Model ID=%s is created at %d.%n", chatCompletions.getId(), chatCompletions.getCreated());
        for (ChatChoice choice : chatCompletions.getChoices()) {
            ChatMessage message = choice.getMessage();
            System.out.printf("Index: %d, Chat Role: %s.%n", choice.getIndex(), message.getRole());
            System.out.println("Message:");
            System.out.println(message.getContent());
        }

        System.out.println();
        CompletionsUsage usage = chatCompletions.getUsage();
        System.out.printf("Usage: number of prompt token is %d, "
                        + "number of completion token is %d, and number of total tokens in request and response is %d.%n",
                usage.getPromptTokens(), usage.getCompletionTokens(), usage.getTotalTokens());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getChatCompletion();
    }

}
```

show error:

```
com.azure.core.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"DeploymentNotFound", "message":"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again."}}"
Exception in thread "main"  at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxyBase.java:347)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.ensureExpectedStatus(SyncRestProxy.java:130)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.handleRestReturnType(SyncRestProxy.java:213)
com.azure.core.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"DeploymentNotFound", "message":"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again."}}"
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxyBase.java:347)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.ensureExpectedStatus(SyncRestProxy.java:130)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.handleRestReturnType(SyncRestProxy.java:213)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.invoke(SyncRestProxy.java:81)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.invoke(SyncRestProxy.java:81)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.invoke(RestProxyBase.java:109)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.invoke(RestProxy.java:91)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy3.getChatCompletionsSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.invoke(RestProxyBase.java:109)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.implementation.OpenAIClientImpl.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClientImpl.java:757)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.invoke(RestProxy.java:91)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy3.getChatCompletionsSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.implementation.OpenAIClientImpl.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClientImpl.java:757)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClient.java:255)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClient.java:255)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletions(OpenAIClient.java:381)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.getChatCompletion(AzureOpenAIClient.java:37)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletions(OpenAIClient.java:381)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.main(AzureOpenAIClient.java:55)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.getChatCompletion(AzureOpenAIClient.java:37)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.main(AzureOpenAIClient.java:55)
13:35:44.075 [main] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase - Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"DeploymentNotFound", "message":"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again."}}"
com.azure.core.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"DeploymentNotFound", "message":"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again."}}"
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxyBase.java:347)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.ensureExpectedStatus(SyncRestProxy.java:130)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.handleRestReturnType(SyncRestProxy.java:213)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.SyncRestProxy.invoke(SyncRestProxy.java:81)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.invoke(RestProxyBase.java:109)
    at com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.invoke(RestProxy.java:91)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy3.getChatCompletionsSync(Unknown Source)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.implementation.OpenAIClientImpl.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClientImpl.java:757)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletionsWithResponse(OpenAIClient.java:255)
    at com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient.getChatCompletions(OpenAIClient.java:381)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.getChatCompletion(AzureOpenAIClient.java:37)
    at com.dolphin.soa.post.config.ai.azure.AzureOpenAIClient.main(AzureOpenAIClient.java:55)
```

I have checked all the configuration and make sure the endpoint was correct, the deployment was created more than 10 hours. Am I missing something? This is the dependencies:

```
implementation'com.azure:azure-ai-openai:1.0.0-beta.1'
```

I have already tried to upgrade the azure openai dependencies version to `1.0.0-beta.2` but still could not fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same error in my environment.

> [main] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase
> Status code 404, "{"error":{"code":"DeploymentNotFound",
> "message":"The API deployment for this resource does not exist. If you created the deployment within the last 5 minutes, please wait a moment and try again."}}"

[image]

In your code, at **`deploymentOrModelId`**, you have given **`gpt-35-turbo`** but you need to mention your deployment name. You can get the deployment name using the portal below.

**Portal:**

[image]

I tried with the same code change deployment id into **`deployment1`** it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClient;
import com.azure.ai.openai.OpenAIClientBuilder;
import com.azure.ai.openai.models.*;
import com.azure.core.credential.AzureKeyCredential;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void getChatCompletion(){
        String azureOpenaiKey = "";
        String endpoint = "https://xxxxx.openai.azure.com/";
        String deploymentOrModelId = "deployment1";

        OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(endpoint)
                .credential(new AzureKeyCredential(azureOpenaiKey))
                .buildClient();

        List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.SYSTEM).setContent("You are a helpful assistant."));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent("Does Azure OpenAI support customer managed keys?"));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.ASSISTANT).setContent("Yes, customer managed keys are supported by Azure OpenAI?"));
        chatMessages.add(new ChatMessage(ChatRole.USER).setContent("Do other Azure Cognitive Services support this too?"));

        ChatCompletions chatCompletions = client.getChatCompletions(deploymentOrModelId, new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages));

        System.out.printf("Model ID=%s is created at %d.%n", chatCompletions.getId(), chatCompletions.getCreated());
        for (ChatChoice choice : chatCompletions.getChoices()) {
            ChatMessage message = choice.getMessage();
            System.out.printf("Index: %d, Chat Role: %s.%n", choice.getIndex(), message.getRole());
            System.out.println("Message:");
            System.out.println(message.getContent());
        }

        System.out.println();
        CompletionsUsage usage = chatCompletions.getUsage();
        System.out.printf("Usage: number of prompt token is %d, "
                        + "number of completion token is %d, and number of total tokens in request and response is %d.%n",
                usage.getPromptTokens(), usage.getCompletionTokens(), usage.getTotalTokens());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getChatCompletion();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Model ID=chatcmpl-xxxxx is created at 168776xxx.
Index: 0, Chat Role: assistant.
Message:
Yes, most Azure Cognitive Services support customer managed keys for enhanced security and compliance. Some of the popular services that support customer managed keys include Azure Cognitive Search, Azure Speech Services, Azure Language Understanding, and Azure Computer Vision.

Usage: number of prompt token is 59, number of completion token is 44, and number of total tokens in request and response is 103.
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure OpenAI client library for Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/ai-openai-readme?view=azure-java-preview#chat-completions)